# Bottom Tabs are not displaying in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Bottom tabs are not displaying and crashes the application by giving following error:

```
 ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: shouldBeUseWeb
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
          This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

My Navigator code in which I have declared two navigators, one is stack and other is tabs:

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';
import FavoritesScreen from "../screens/FavoritesScreen";
import Colors from "../constants/Colors";

const MealsNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Categories: CategoriesScreen,
    CategoryMeals: {
        screen: CategoryMealsScreen,
    },
    MealDetail: MealDetailScreen,
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Platform.OS === "android" ? Colors.primaryColor : "white" },
        headerTintColor: Platform.OS === "android" ? "white" : Colors.primaryColor,
    }
});

const MealsFavTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Meals: MealsNavigator,
    Favorites: FavoritesScreen
});

export default createAppContainer(MealsFavTabNavigator);
```

Answer (score 1):

[createStackNavigator](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/stack/src/navigators/createStackNavigator.tsx) and [createBottomTabNavigator](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/bottom-tabs/src/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.tsx) are factories

Fist return jsx functions/component:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
```

Then use jsx component:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home">
    <Tab.Screen
      name="One"
      component={SettingsStack}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="HomeOne"
      component={HomeStack}
      …
```

Take a look at my [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/bottom-navigation-example)